# Does document.getElementById return a live dom element?

Tags: javascript

Does `document.getElementById` in JavaScript return a live DOM element? I am interested to know for performance reason

Comment: What would you consider a "live" DOM element, and what would a "non-live" DOM element look like ?

Comment: elementList = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
elementList is a non-live NodeList of element objects.

Comment: Can you give an example of what a live element does?

Comment: If you mean "live" like after edited the DOM, the answer is yes.

Comment: @GibboK the function returns a reference to the actual DOM element. If, for example, you get a reference to an "input" element, and then afterwards the user types something, you'll see that typing reflected in the "value" property of the object.

Comment: How would that example using `querySelectorAll` be any different than using any other method to retrieve an element from the DOM ?

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092822/how-to-convert-array-of-live-dom-elements-into-live-nodelist) has some relevance with regards to "live".

Comment: there is a library called **live_el.js**, to do just that. google **live_el.js**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The distinction between standard and "live" is usually used for *lists* of elements. `document.getElementById` returns a single object reference to a DOM node. Once the node is acquired the reference will always point to the same node.

<sub>HTML for the example:</sub>

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

<sub>JS for the example:</sub>

```
var foo,
    bar;
foo = document.getElementById('foo'); //gets the div
bar = document.getElementById('bar'); //null
foo.setAttribute('id', 'bar');
console.log(foo.id); //'bar'
console.log(bar.id); //TypeError
```

The references don't get updated just because the ID of the element might have changed.

This is in contrast to something like `document.getElementsByTagName` which returns a list of elements with the given tag. The list will automatically update when elements are added to or removed from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

yeah only certain getEleme and querySele functions return live node lists

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).