# How to i reset a field value with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make the value in  `quantity` show as `1` if its not valid.

```
<input type = "number" id = "quantity" value="1" onchange="Validatequantity()" />
```

---

```
function Validatequantity() {   
    var num = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
    if  (num < 1 || num > 10 ) {
        alert('Invalid ticket number ...Should be between 1-10');
        num = 1; // reset part is here(don't work)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with the variable make it a reference to the element than its value:

```
function Validatequantity() {   
    var num = document.getElementById('quantity');
    if  (num.value < 1 || num.value > 10 ) {
        num.value = 1;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function Validatequantity() {
    var num = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
    if  (num < 1 || num > 10 ) {
        alert('Invalid ticket number ...Should be between 1-10');
        num = 1; // reset part is here(don't work)
        document.getElementById('quantity').value = 1; // Set input value to 1
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    } 
}
```

Comment: isn't it same as `num=1` because `num = document.getElementById('quantity').value`

Comment: It is not `live node`, I think

Comment: You can give me a link to an article talking about it so that i can learn ...it works btw

Comment: @user2650277 http://stackoverflow.com/a/19145320/2025923 the element is `live` but not the `value`